# jQuery の :visible に相当するセレクタ

Tags: html, css, html5

jQuery の :visible に相当するセレクタを CSS で記述する方法はありますか。

たとえば、ボタンが横に複数並んでいる状態で右端のボタンのみ角丸にしたい場合

```css
last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

と記述したりしますが、条件によってボタンの表示／非表示が切り替わる場合、表示されているボタンの右端にスタイルを適用したい、というような要件を実現したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ありません。可能であれば、 jQuery を使用するか、 `:visible` セレクタ相当の機能を JavaScript で実装することをおすすめします。

実際には、 `display` プロパティに関する装飾のみをインラインで行えば、**属性セレクタ**を用いて表示、非表示によって装飾を変更することも出来ると思いますが、常に **`style` 属性の値に気を使わなければならない**ため、良い方法とはいえません。

また、もし要素の追加、削除が自由に行えるのであれば、要素を非表示にするのではなく、逐一要素を追加、削除するという方法も考えられますが、これも手間がかかり、使用出来る場面が限られると思います。